# Redirecting to login page after session time out

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

When the session is timed out, the liferay displays it in a form of a banner at the top of the page.

How to override this behavior to redirect the application to the login page after session times out?

[image: Thanks!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting this property to true

> session.timeout.redirect.on.expire=false

More info here https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/20850305